# My search function won't work when i add another function like Notification

Tags: php

This is my code for the search, it works fine when the notification function is not added. But once i added "Notification" function it would not make this "Search" function work. please help

Edit: i added the code on how i am showing the data of the table where i have the search function.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#search").keyup(function(){

                if( $(this).val() != "")
                {
                    $("#table tbody>tr").hide();
                    $("#table td:contains-ci('" + $(this).val() + "')").parent("tr").show();
                }
                else
                {

                    $("#table tbody>tr").show();
                }
            });
        });

        $.extend($.expr[":"], 
        {
            "contains-ci": function(elem, i, match, array) 
            {
                return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || $(elem).text() || "").toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
            }
        });
```

then this is the Html code for its input

```
    <input type="search" id="search" class = "search" name = "search" placeholder="Search...">
```

then this is the code on how i populate the table in my page

```
    <label id = "title">Manage Licenses</label><br/> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style = "padding-bottom : 20px;">
            <?php
            $qry = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbllicense, tblrequests WHERE ExpirationDate < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND 
            tblrequests.ID = Request_ID AND tblrequests.Status = 'accepted' ORDER BY ExpirationDate");
            $qry->execute();
            $rows = $qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $expiredcount = 0;
            ?>
            <table class = "table" id = "table">
            <thead>
                <th>Record ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>License Type</th>
                <th>Expiration</th>
                <th>Options</th>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                foreach ($rows as $row) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?= $row["Request_ID"] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $row["txtFName"] . " " . $row["txtSurname"] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $row["txtEmail"] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $row["txtLicense"] ?></td>
                        <td><?= date("M d, Y", strtotime($row["ExpirationDate"])) ?></td>
                        <td><input type = "button" class = "btnAccept" value = "Renew" onclick = "renew(<?= $row["Request_ID"] ?>)"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
                </thead>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

When i add this funtion (Notification). The search would not work properly and when i put an input in the search form, the results will just be blank.

```
    <li style = "float:right">
        <div style = "float:right">
        <?php
        $qry = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbllicense, tblrequests WHERE ExpirationDate < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND 
            tblrequests.ID = Request_ID AND tblrequests.Status = 'accepted'
            UNION
            SELECT * FROM tblvisa, tblrequests WHERE ExpirationDate < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND 
            tblrequests.ID = Request_ID AND tblrequests.Status = 'accepted' ORDER BY ExpirationDate"
            );
            $qry->execute();
            $rows = $qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ($qry->rowCount()) {

            echo '<img width=15 height=13 src="img/alert.png" />';

        } 

         ?>
        </div>
        <a href='#' id = "notificationLink" class = "notificationLink" title = "Notification"><img src="img/notification.png"
        style = " position : relative; width : 15px; height : 13px;"/></a>
        <div id="notificationContainer">
        <div id="notificationTitle">Notifications</div>
        <div id="notificationBody" class="scrollbar2">

        <?php
            $qry = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbllicense, tblrequests WHERE ExpirationDate < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND 
            tblrequests.ID = Request_ID AND tblrequests.Status = 'accepted' ORDER BY ExpirationDate");
            $qry->execute();
            $rows = $qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $expiredcount = 0;
            ?>
            <table class = "table" id = "table">
            <thead>
                <?php
                foreach ($rows as $row) {
                    $expiredcount++;
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href='_admin_business_license.php' style = "color: white;" class = "link">The Request <?= $row["Request_ID"] ?> is expired or about to expire on
                        <?= date("M d, Y", strtotime($row["ExpirationDate"])) ?> from the Business License</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            <?php
            $qry = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblvisa, tblrequests WHERE ExpirationDate < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND 
            tblrequests.ID = Request_ID AND tblrequests.Status = 'accepted' ORDER BY ExpirationDate");
            $qry->execute();
            $rows = $qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $expiredcount1 = 0;
            ?>

                <?php
                foreach ($rows as $row) {
                    $expiredcount1++;
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href='_admin_visa.php' style = "color: white" class = "link">The Request <?= $row["Request_ID"] ?> is expired or about to expire on
                        <?= date("M d, Y", strtotime($row["ExpirationDate"])) ?> from the Visa</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="notificationFooter"><a href="notification.php">See All</a></div>
        </div>
        </li>
```

Comment: Did you check console for error ?

Comment: yes i did checked the console errors, but i did not find any error related to it.

Comment: just run your code and check your page source, have id "search" come only one time in your html ?

Comment: @MahipalPatel yes, i only used it for the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for those who answered my questions :)

i found out the reason why its leaving a blank page is because im searching for the same "table" of Notification and the admin page.

i changed the id of the "table"(s) causing conflict to the code of Search.

```
     $("#search").keyup(function(){

            if( $(this).val() != "")
            {
                $("#searchtable tbody>tr").hide();
                $("#searchtable td:contains-ci('" + $(this).val() + "')").parent("tr").show();
            }
            else
            {

                $("#table tbody>tr").show();
            }
        });
    });
```

this is the new id for the table that the search must run through

```
    <table class = "table" id = "searchtable">
        <thead>
            <th>Record ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>License Type</th>
            <th>Expiration</th>
            <th>Options</th>
            <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $row["Request_ID"] ?></td>
                    <td><?= $row["txtFName"] . " " . $row["txtSurname"] ?></td>
                    <td><?= $row["txtEmail"] ?></td>
                    <td><?= $row["txtLicense"] ?></td>
                    <td><?= date("M d, Y", strtotime($row["ExpirationDate"])) ?></td>
                    <td><input type = "button" class = "btnAccept" value = "Renew" onclick = "renew(<?= $row["Request_ID"] ?>)"/></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
            </thead>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your search function is searching in tbody but you only have thead in your code.

Unless there is more code we don't see (which i doubt since you close the table) then i think that is the problem

change

```
$("#table tbody>tr").hide();
```

to

```
$("#table thead>tr").hide();
```

and

```
$("#table tbody>tr").show();
```

to

```
$("#table thead>tr").show();
```

You also need to do the following

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        var txtVal = $(this).val();
        if(txtVal != "")
        {
            $("#table > thead > tr").show();

            $.each($("#table > thead > tr"), function (i, o) {
                var match = $("td:contains-ci('" + txtVal + "')",this)
                if (match.length > 0) $(this).show();
                else $(this).hide();
            });
        }
        else
        {

            $("#table thead > tr").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i tried your code, the result is: the data in the page are still shown but not filtered out the unrelated data

Comment: It does help to stop the code from leaving the page blank once i typed in, now the problem is: it returns all of the data